# App size increases for 11MB after implementing adMob ads

Tags: libgdx, admob

I noticed that the size of my libgdx app drastically increased after implementing admob ads. Increase was more than 11MB. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be 11mb just because of admob. Make sure you did not add other resources (drawable) or libraries at the same time you added admob? To verify you can just try temporarily removing (only) admob and see of it really gets reduced again by 11mb. But I highly doubt that only admob related things would take 11mb.

Again by **size**, I'm assuming you are talking about apk size. And that is for what I say cannot be something like 11 mb of increase. But if you are talking about memory on storage used after installation then it is possible and there is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Increased by 11 MB that big !! for my experience I only noticed 1 or 2 MB change, how are you using **admob** ?

if you are using like this as dependency :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

you should know taht you are using every feature of Google Play Services, including location services.

if you only need ads try use this instead:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

also I recommend to use **Proguard** to reduce the size of APK by removed unused **classes** from the library, try add this in your **Proguard** config file

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
    public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
    public *;
}
```

good luck

Comment: Actually, I am using         compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$admobVersion" and admob version 8.3.0. I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwAN4LMXo58